# using array's delete_if command

Tags: ruby, arrays

Lets say,

```
script = Array.new
script.push("/home/dexter/constant.sh")
script.push("/home/dexter/constant_validation.rb")
script.push("/home/dexter/jobs/reporter.rb")
```

Now when I use array's delete_if method,

```
script.compact.delete_if {|s| s =~ /constant/}
```

This should remove elements from array containing "constant". This is the output I get when i perform it under interactive ruby.

```
puts script => ["/home/dexter/jobs/reporter.rb"]
```

I am pushing the elements into the array with the help of regular expression matching.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: What is the output you get when you put it in a script?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija when put in code, the delete_if seems to be ineffective. After operating delete_if on script array I get,

`puts script => ["/home/dexter/constant.sh","/home/dexter/constant_validation.rb","/home/dexter/jobs/reporter.rb"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. so the mistake i was doing in the script was,

I was adding elements into the script array in my script with the help of regular expressions.
So when I did a class check on the elements of the array i found that they were of type "MatchData" and hence the delete_if was not working.

Answer (score 1):

While `delete_if` is destructive and work on the message receiver, since you use `compact` method which returns different instance from `self`, the instance you send `delete_if` message to, is different from the `script`.

So, you will get desired result if you run `script.compact!` then `script.delete_if`.

There is no `delete_if!` since `delete_if` itself modify `self`.

Comment: even if I do not use compact like script.delete_if I am not getting it correct

Comment: `compact!` returns `nil` if no changes were made

Comment: then, should not rely on return value then..

Answer (score 0):

```
script = Array.new
script.push("/home/dexter/constant.sh")
script.push("/home/dexter/constant_validation.rb")
script.push("/home/dexter/jobs/reporter.rb")

script
#=> ["/home/dexter/constant.sh",
 "/home/dexter/constant_validation.rb",
 "/home/dexter/jobs/reporter.rb"]
```

As @shigeya said above, `compact` returns different instance of `self`. You can verify that as:

```
script.object_id
#=>72421740
script.compact.object_id
#=> 71512710
```

Thus, by using `compact` in chain with `delete_if`, you are making changes on the object array returned by `script.compact` and not `script` itself,

```
`delete_if` **will** destruct the calling array
script.delete_if { |s| s =~ /constant/ }
=> ["/home/dexter/jobs/reporter.rb"]

script
=> ["/home/dexter/jobs/reporter.rb"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one line it would need to look like:

```
script.tap{|s| s.compact}.delete_if {|s| s =~ /constant/}
```

Otherwise your changes won't affect `script`.

Comment: thanks for the effective answer..was trying to add up your reputation but looks like I need a min of 15 to do that. Anyways, thanks for the help.